# Plotting fills with python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How could i plot two functions like in the image. My question is not how to exactly define the functions from the plot but i am looking for a functionality for filling the areas under the functions: same color the common area(white) and different the others as in the pic (grey and green striped). Image this as a pdf[image]

Answer (score 2):

The matplotlib example gallery has a plot showing how to do this:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html

Usually, looking at the following page tells you how to do various things:

http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html